# Link from within Bootstrap 3 popover fails for mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to place a popover that contains some hyperlinks, and hides itself upon whacking one of the hyperlinks. It works fine when activated by trackpad, but fails (no linked page appears) when activated by mouse (variant "Busticated").

This seems to be related to hiding the popover: if I use setTimeout to slightly delay the popover-hide, all is good (variant "Working"). But though I have a variant which seems to work in all my test cases, the number of questions it raises bothers me:

- Shouldn't the Bootstrap library (if not lower layers) do all the worrying about input device characteristics?
- Am I doing something else wrong that causes this misbehavior?
- Is the magic number "100" (milliseconds) going to fix this for all users?

(Mis)behavior observed in OS X Safari and OS X Firefox.
"Trackpad" is the built-in trackpad of a MacBook Pro.
"Mouse" is a Bluetooth Apple Mighty Mouse (the one with the track-bead).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrep/ekpx0574/2/)

```
  $('#rss_aggregator_popover').popover({
      html: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      trigger: 'manual',
      content: function () {
          return $('#rss_aggregator_html').html()
      }
  })
  .on("click", function () {
      $(this).popover("toggle");
  })
  /* Working */
  // .on('focusout', function() {
  //   setTimeout(function(t) {
  //     $(t).popover("toggle");
  //   }, 100, this);
  // })
  /* Busticated */
  .on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).popover("toggle");
  })
```

[Working site](https://developer.akamai.com/)

(Edited to clarify the "real" question, "why????")

Comment: your fiddle works perfectly for me... (edited to say, I stand corrected, it does break in win/safari)

Comment: Thanks for trying. This platform variation in behavior is not encouraging ... I'm also worried about the magic number "100" in my "Working" variant ... might there be computers, or mice, or browsers, or moon-phases where I need 101, or 110, or 1000?

Comment: Truly. The weird thing is, I commented out the bit to hide the popover, and the links still do not work. Very strange.